# Setting up interceptors in vuejs axios

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have setup axios with interceptors this way

```
const axiosConfig = {
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api',
    timeout: 30000
};

axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => { // intercept the global error
    console.log("response is", response);
    return response
}, (error) => {
    console.log("errors are", error);
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
        // if the error is 401 and hasent already been retried
        alert("You will need to login to access this");
        window.location.href = '/auth/login'
        return
    }
    if (error.response.status === 404) {
        window.location.href = '/'
        return
    }
});

Vue.prototype.$axios = axios.create(axiosConfig)
```

But the above interceptors dont work.Where am i going wrong? The console.log() messages fail to work.

Comment: could u try writing the interceptors outside vue, in window context rather

Comment: hey man,, did you get the chance to see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sending you minimal working example of how to intercept ajax before request is started. I have a button on the page, and then I'm binding it to pull some data, but before that I have console.log'ed the interceptor message => you can replace that with your logic.

Hope that can help you get started..

```js
// let's intercept axios ajax call BEFORE it starts
var INTER = axios.interceptors.request.use(
  function(config){ console.log('intercepted!'); return config;},
  function(error){return Promise.reject(error);}
);
// function to pull remote data
function pullData(){
  var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  axios.get( url )
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.status);
  })
  .catch(function (error) { console.log(error); });
}

// reff the button on the page
var b = document.getElementById('b');
// bind to click event
b.addEventListener('click', pullData, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.8/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.17.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<button id="b">Click to pull http req resource</button>
```

Comment: did you run code snippet and see my example? I've added interceptor for axios `get`, and in console you can see it before data is pulled

Comment: i can see yours is working on the browser, but i have setup axios globally calling it via this.$axios, and then my requests are on different components. I really dont know why its failing?

Comment: can you post your full code, either here or on jsbin?